# Is $\mathbb{R}$ equipotent to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\mathbb{R}$ equipotent to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the real numbers and the complex numbers have the same cardinality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245141/do-the-real-numbers-and-the-complex-numbers-have-the-same-cardinality)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer : Yes

Hint : Since $\mathbb{R}$ is equipotent to $]0,1[$, you just have to prove $]0,1[$ is equipotent to $]0,1[^2$. Now you can use decimal expansion and the same kind of trickery you would use to show $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$ are equipotent.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I detest decimal expansions. I would be interested in other proofs than the standard one (which is in Joel's reply) that avoid this.

(By the way, to show that $|\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|$ I prefer the argument that $(m,n)\mapsto 2^m3^n$ is injective by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.)

For example, we could use that for an infinite field $K$, its algebraic closure has the same cardinality. (This follows because $|K^n|=|K|$ and then $|K[x]|=|\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}K^n|=|\mathbb{N}||K|=|K|$.) Hence $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{C}|=|\mathbb{R}^2|$.

Who knows a (edit: non-circular) argument?

A nice (general) argument is based on some elementary point-set topology, as described [at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property): any compact Hausdorff space with more than two point, and all of whose singletons are non-open, must be uncountable.

Comment: But... isn't this circular?

Comment: @Theo: yes, $|K^n|=|K|$ is of course what we want to prove. I didn't pay attention. I now recall a better argument, see my edit.

Comment: Well, since you ask for variants: Geometrically much more appealing (for the case of $\mathbb{R}$) than decimal expansion is to use a [Peano curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

Comment: Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder is generally the way to go in situations like this where it's awkward to construct a bijection but not too bad to construct surjections or injections.

Comment: Just because a compact Hausdorff space satisfying properties is uncountable does NOT mean that you know its cardinality.  Uncountable means that the cardinality is larger than the smallest infinite cardinal.  There are quite a large number of cardinals which satisfy that condition.

Comment: OK the proof that a perfect set is uncountable actually shows there is a copy of the Cantor set in it.  But if you reject writing in binary, now you need to show that the Cantor set has power at least c in some other way.

Comment: @Aaron: yes, I was not very sharp yesterday. I was at the same time thinking about two things: showing that $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equipotent, and showing that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, both without using decimal expansions.