# Do the real numbers and the complex numbers have the same cardinality?

Tags: complex-numbers, cardinals

So it's easy to show that the rationals and the integers have the same size, using everyone's favorite spiral-around-the-grid.

Can the approach be extended to say that the set of complex numbers has the same cardinality as the reals?

Comment: One can show that $|\mathbb R| = |\mathbb R^2| = |\mathbb C|$

Comment: It's quite sad, but it's easier to write an answer than finding the duplicate. And I am **sure** this question has been asked before.

Comment: The best treatment of this in an existing answer is probably [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/183383/12042).

Answer (score 34):

Yes.

$$|\mathbb R|=2^{\aleph_0}; |\mathbb C|=|\mathbb{R\times R}|=|\mathbb R|^2.$$

We have if so:

$$|\mathbb C|=|\mathbb R|^2 =(2^{\aleph_0})^2 = 2^{\aleph_0\cdot 2}=2^{\aleph_0}=|\mathbb R|$$

If one wishes to write down an explicit function, one can use a function of $\mathbb{N\times 2\to N}$, and combine it with a bijection between $2^\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What is $2^\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 16):

Of course. I will show it on numbers in $[0,1)$ and $[0,1)\times[0,1)$. Consider $z=x+iy$ with $x=0.x_1x_2x_3\ldots$ and $y=0.y_1y_2y_3\ldots$ their decimal expansions (the standard, greedy ones with no $9^\omega$ as a suffix). Then the number $f(z)=0.x_1y_1x_2y_2x_3y_3\ldots$ is real and this map is clearly injective on the above mentioned sets. Generalization to the whole $\mathbb C$ is straightforward. This gives $\#\mathbb C\leq\#\mathbb R$. the other way around is obvious.

Comment: This requires a bit more work. The map isn’t well-defined until you deal with the $0.4999\dots=0.5000\dots$ issue; if you deal with that straightforwardly, it’a nor surjective.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, they all all (complex) rational hence of no interest for the sets of continuum cardinality. I'll add a comment.

Comment: And btw, usually a string with suffix $9^\omega$ is not considered to be an _expansion_ (it is only a _representation_), in the usual greedy expansions as defined by Rényi in 1957.

Comment: I’ve never seen anyone make a distinction between *representation* and *expansion*, and I very much doubt that the distinction can be considered standard; certainly it does not qualify as well-known, so if you use it, you need to explain it.

Comment: And yes, I know that only countably many numbers are affected and that this does not affect the result, but I don’t know that the OP knows this.

Comment: The sequence $a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ _represents_ $x$ if $x=\sum a_i\beta^{-i}$ (let's say it is a property of the string), you can speak about a greedy one (maximal in the lexicographical order) etc., but then, you only add more properties. The _Rényi expansion_ of $x$ is the one given by $x_0=x$, $a_i=\lfloor \beta x_{i-1}\rfloor$, $x_i=\beta x_{i-1}-a_i$, which is an _algorithm_ for obtaining the representations, and then you can speak about _expanding_ the number. The fact that such representation is greedy (in the sense of maximality w.r.t. some order) has to be proved.

Comment: Yes, I inferred all that from your earlier comments. It doesn’t affect mine.

Comment: your statement "the other way around is obvious" might be lost on some beginners. can you show how $f$ is surjective?

Comment: This argument seems strange to me. Let me show why. Consider a real number  $a$ with $\ldots x_2 x_1 x_0 . y_0 y_1 y_2 \ldots$ its decimal expansion. Then the number $f(a) = \ldots x_2 y_2 x_1 y_1 x_0 y_0$ is an integer, right? Thus $\# \mathbb R \le \# \mathbb Z$. Do you see the issue?

Comment: @DaBler That doesn't work in the case you mention; integers have to have finite length as strings, so your f(a) isn't actually an integer, or even a number of any sort. But decimal expansions have countably infinite length, so this argument (modulo the issues mentioned earlier around non-unique representation) works fine for interweaving two decimal expansions. Or any number of expansions, for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

Consult #4b in [http://faculty.lasierra.edu/~jvanderw/classes/m415a03/hw8ans.pdf](http://faculty.lasierra.edu/%7Ejvanderw/classes/m415a03/hw8ans.pdf).

A straightforward bijection $B : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is: $B(a,b) = a + bi$. I omit the verification of injectivity and surjectivity. Then $|C| = |\mathbb{R}^2|$.
The separate result that $|\mathbb{R}^k| = |\mathbb{R}| \; \forall \; k \in \mathbb{N}$
implies $|\mathbb{R}^2| = |\mathbb{R}|$. Altogether, $|\mathbb{C}| = |\mathbb{R}^2| = |\mathbb{R}|$.

Answer (score -5):

One particularly nice class of bijections from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb C = \Bbb R^2$, which is in my opinion a little bit similar to the spiral around the grid, is given by the [space-filling curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).

Comment: This is incorrect. Space filling curves are not injective.

Comment: @DanRust: Can you explain why?

Comment: If an injective and surjective curve in the square existed, then this would imply that such a curve is in fact a homeomorphism, as the interval is compact, and the square is Hausdorff. We know they are not homeomorphic as the interval has a cut point and the square does not.