# Can the entire range of 2 dimensions be represented in one dimension?

Tags: infinity

If you consider the $x-y$ plane, any $(x,y)$ point exists with $x\in(-\infty, \infty)$  and $y\in( -\infty,\infty)$. Is it possible to represent any $x,y$ point in only one dimension (e.g. one number)?

For example consider a discrete $8\times 8$ grid. You can represent this as $x,y$ coordinates but you can also represent it as one number in the range $[0,64)$. Can this be done in a non-discrete setting?

Comment: Related: [Does ℝ2 contain more numbers than ℝ1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247696/does-mathbb-r2-contain-more-numbers-than-mathbb-r1) and [Examples of bijective map from ℝ3→ℝ](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr)